# Filter nav menu items HTML tags and wrap inner text with span

Tags: functions, menus, filters, themes

I am using the following filter to select `<a>` tags from a specific menu that have no attributes (href, class, etc.) and replace them with `<button>` tags.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'filter_empty_anchor_items', 10, 2 );
function filter_empty_anchor_items( $items, $args ) {
  if( $args->theme_location == 'want-to-navigation')  {
    $pattern = '/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/s';
    $items = preg_replace($pattern, '<button>$1</button>', $items );
  }
  return $items;
}
```

The filter itself is working, but I need to adjust the regular expression or run a second pass of a separate regular expression to select the text within the `<button>` tag and wrap it with a `<span>` tag.

The following `wp_nav_menu` code is being used to display the menu with a `<svg>` attached to the `link_after` argument.

```
$args = array(
  "theme_location" => "want-to-navigation",
  "menu_id" => "want-to-navigation",
  "container" => "false",
  "container_id" => "want-to",
  "container_class" => "quicklinks",
  "link_after" => '<svg viewBox="0 0 448 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m432 256c0 17.69-14.33 32.01-32 32.01h-144v144c0 17.69-14.33 31.99-32 31.99s-32-14.3-32-31.99v-144h-144c-17.67 0-32-14.32-32-32.01s14.33-31.99 32-31.99h144v-144c0-17.69 14.33-32.01 32-32.01s32 14.32 32 32.01v144h144c17.7-.01 32 14.29 32 31.99z"/></svg>',
);
echo wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

An example: Select `<button>`**Select this text and wrap with span**`<svg></svg></button>`

Comment: Have you looked into a custom nav walker? That would likely give you even more control over the markup and probably not require regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `link_before` in your `wp_nav_menu` `$args` and add opening/closing span tags:

```
$args = [
    'link_before' => '<span>',
    /* Add closing </span> to link_after */
    'link_after' => '</span><svg>...</svg>',

    // Other args
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your solution in combination with an adjusted `preg_replace` pattern to achieve my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with assistance from TheDeadMedic.

I added the `<svg>` code to the replacement value in the `preg_replace` function, then added the opening and closing `<span>` tags to the `link_before` and `link_after` arguments in the theme template file.

Nav menu items filter

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'filter_empty_anchor_items', 10, 2 );
function filter_empty_anchor_items( $items, $args ) {
  if( $args->theme_location == 'want-to-navigation') {
    $pattern = '/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/s';
    $replacement = '<button>$1<svg viewBox="0 0 448 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m432 256c0 17.69-14.33 32.01-32 32.01h-144v144c0 17.69-14.33 31.99-32 31.99s-32-14.3-32-31.99v-144h-144c-17.67 0-32-14.32-32-32.01s14.33-31.99 32-31.99h144v-144c0-17.69 14.33-32.01 32-32.01s32 14.32 32 32.01v144h144c17.7-.01 32 14.29 32 31.99z"/></svg></button>';
    $items = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $items );
  }
  return $items;
}
```

Nav menu output

```
$args = array(
  "theme_location" => "want-to-navigation",
  "menu_id" => "want-to-navigation",
  "container" => "false",
  "container_id" => "want-to",
  "container_class" => "quicklinks",
  "link_before" => '<span>',
  "link_after" => '</span>',
);
```

I hope this is helpful to others needing to achieve something similar.